# ASP.NET MVC behaviour if an exception is thrown

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What does ASP.NET MVC do if an exception is thrown in controller, view or model?

Comment: The same thing that happens in any other .NET code if an exception is thrown.

Comment: i am sorry, but have you tried write something like `throw new Exception("Testing asp.net mvc behaviour");` somewhere in action :) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the exception is not caught and you're not using the HandleError attribute, the exception will bubble up and result in IIS returning an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Heh, well, hopefully you have your web.config setup such that your users don't see the dreaded YSOD :)